# How to code a linear regression from scratch in Python using the (log)likelihood as objective function?

Tags: python, regression, linear-regression

I am trying to code a linear regression from scratch in Python.

There exist multiple examples and tutorials online, however it seems that all of these tutorials use the sum of squared residuals or mean squared error as objective function. I want to have a manual implementation of regression where the objective function is the log-likelihood. I also do not want to use gradient descent or a numerical optimization method. I want to mathematically derive the ML estimator (under the assumption of a certain distribution) and compute it in python. For example, the Poisson distribution has a single parameter and its ML estimator is the sample mean.

I am a mathematician and have trouble manually coding this. Ideally I would like to find an example of similar code.

Comment: Would a logistic regression be more suitable than linear regression? If your objective function is log-likelihood, then presumably you're ultimately trying to predict probabilities in [0,1]. So typically it makes sense for the logit, rather than the probability itself, to be a linear function of the predictor variables. If that's your use case, then a web search for *"logistic regression python without sklearn"* brings up some useful resources.

Comment: I am not trying to perform logistic regression, but a Poisson regression. However I will take a look at the logistic regression suggestion.